# how to instantiate a component in a game object controlling by a variable bolean? unity

Tags: unity, c#

I have this script

```
public HingeJoint hide;
public bool ver;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    hide = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (ver)
    {
        Destroy(hide);
    }

}
```

I can destroy the component but I need to re-instantiate the component

Comment: Presumably you tried AddComponent — did anything go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
hide = gameObject.AddComponent<HingeJoint>();
```